# Updating Navbar Links in React on "Become a Seller" Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, navbar

I am facing a challenge related to updating navbar links dynamically. I want the navbar to display "Logo," "Seller Home," "About," and "Sell a Product" links when the user clicks on the "Become a Seller" link.

I am using:

```json
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react": "^16.13.1"
```

**Issue Description:**

- I want to dynamically update the navbar links based on user actions, specifically when a user clicks on the "Become a Seller" link.
- After extensive research and trial and error, I haven't been able to find a clear solution or relevant resources that address this specific scenario.

**What I've Tried:**

I've looked through various tutorials and documentation but couldn't find a clear example or explanation related to updating navbar links dynamically.

**What I'm Looking For:**

1. How can I dynamically update the navbar to display only "Logo," "Seller Home," "About," and "Sell a Product" links when the user clicks on "Become a Seller"?
2. Are there any React concepts or features I should focus on to achieve this particular behavior?

**Navbar.js:**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';
import { MdKeyboardArrowDown } from 'react-icons/md';
import { FaCartArrowDown } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Navbar as BootstrapNavbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Navbar.css';

const MyNavbar = ({ logout, isAuthenticated }) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const logout_user = () => {
    logout();
    setRedirect(true);
  };

  const guestLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <li className='nav-item mr-3'>
        <Link className='nav-link' to='/login'>
          Login
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className='nav-item mr-3'>
        <Link className='nav-link' to='/sellerhome'>
          Become a Seller
        </Link>
      </li>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const authLinks = () => (
    <li className='nav-item mr-3'>
      <a className='nav-link' href='#!' onClick={logout_user}>
        Logout
      </a>
    </li>
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <BootstrapNavbar expand='lg' bg='light'>
        <Link className='navbar-brand' to='/'>
          Auth System
        </Link>
        <form className='form-inline d-1 d-lg-inline mr-5'>
          <input
            className='form-control mr-sm-1 custom-search-input'
            type='search'
            placeholder='Search'
            aria-label='Search'
          />
        </form>
        <BootstrapNavbar.Toggle aria-controls='navbarNav' />
        <BootstrapNavbar.Collapse id='navbarNav'>
          <Nav className='navbar-nav'>
            <li className='nav-item active mr-3'>
              <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>
                Home <span className='sr-only'>(current)</span>
              </Link>
            </li>

            {/* Add the Cart link */}
            <li className='nav-item mr-3'>
              <Link className='nav-link' to='/cart'>
                More
                <i className='moredown'>
                  <MdKeyboardArrowDown />
                </i>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item mr-3'>
              <Link className='nav-link' to='/cart'>
                Cart
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className='nav-item mr-3'>
              <Link className='nav-link' to='/cart'>
                <FaCartArrowDown />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
          </Nav>
        </BootstrapNavbar.Collapse>
      </BootstrapNavbar>
      {redirect ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Fragment></Fragment>}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

// ... (mapStateToProps and export)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(MyNavbar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is [Conditional Rendering](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering).

Rewrite the code to *conditionally* render a set of "seller links" versus the normal "nav links", based on some local component state.

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';
import { MdKeyboardArrowDown } from "react-icons/md";
import { FaCartArrowDown } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Navbar as BootstrapNavbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";

const MyNavbar = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  const [showSellerLinks, setShowSellerLinks] = useState(false);

  const logout_user = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
    history.replace("/");
  };

  const guestLinks = (
    <>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/login">
          Login
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link
          className="nav-link"
          to="/sellerhome"
          onClick={setShowSellerLinks.bind(null, true)}
        >
          Become a Seller
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>
  );

  const authLinks = (
    <li className="nav-item mr-3">
      <a className="nav-link" href="#!" onClick={logout_user}>
        Logout
      </a>
    </li>
  );

  const navLinks = (
    <>
      <li className="nav-item active mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
          Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </Link>
      </li>
      {/* Add the Cart link */}
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/cart">
          More
          <i className="moredown">
            <MdKeyboardArrowDown />
          </i>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/cart">
          Cart
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/cart">
          <FaCartArrowDown />
        </Link>
      </li>
      {isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
    </>
  );

  const sellerLinks = (
    <>
      <li className="nav-item active mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/logo">
          Logo
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/sellerhome">
          Seller Home
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">
          About
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item mr-3">
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/sell-product">
          Sell a Product
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <BootstrapNavbar expand="lg" bg="light">
      <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
        Auth System
      </Link>
      <form className="form-inline d-1 d-lg-inline mr-5">
        <input
          className="form-control mr-sm-1 custom-search-input"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
      </form>
      <BootstrapNavbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarNav" />
      <BootstrapNavbar.Collapse id="navbarNav">
        <Nav className="navbar-nav">
          {showSellerLinks ? sellerLinks : navLinks}
        </Nav>
      </BootstrapNavbar.Collapse>
    </BootstrapNavbar>
  );
};

export default MyNavbar;
```

### Demo

[image: Edit updating-navbar-links-in-react-on-become-a-seller-click]

[image]

[image]

How you toggle the `showSellerLinks` back to false I leave as an exercise for you to resolve for your app's specific use case.

Comment: Hi ,
Thank you for the quick help and the updated code. It worked well for dynamically rendering the navbar links when clicking "Become a Seller."

I noticed a minor issue: after clicking and getting the desired "Seller Home" links, refreshing the page reverts the links to the default ones. It seems like the state isn't persisting after a refresh. Any suggestions on how to address this?

Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I'm hoping you could provide some guidance. After clicking "Become a Seller" and getting the desired "Seller Home" links, if I refresh the page, the links revert to "Home (current)," "More," "Cart," "Login," and "Become a Seller." It seems like the state isn't persisting after a page refresh. Do you have any suggestions on how to address this?

Comment: @prajithak That's right, React state does not persist through page reloads, it's stored in memory only. You can use localStorage to persist state changes, and initialize the state from localStorage. I've updated the linked sandbox included in my answer.

Comment: Hi,

I appreciate your prompt help and the updated code. I've implemented the changes, but it seems I'm still encountering an issue. Specifically, after clicking "Become a Seller" and getting the desired "Seller Home" links, if I refresh the page, the links revert to "Home (current)," "More," "Cart," "Login," and "Become a Seller."

Could you please provide some guidance on how to address this? I've reviewed the code, but I might be overlooking something.

Thank you for your continued support!

Comment: @prajithak Sure. Use a [lazy initializer function](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) to load any persisted state from localStorage and provide a default state value, and use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on that state to persist it out to localStorage. The persistence is working in the sandbox I provided, so I'm sure it is something trivial you may be missing or overlooking.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and guidance. I implemented the changes using the lazy initializer function and useEffect as you suggested. However, the issue still persists. After clicking "Become a Seller" and getting the desired "Seller Home" links, when I navigate back to the index page, it continues to display only the seller links.

I've thoroughly reviewed the code, but I'm unable to identify the root cause. Could you please provide further assistance or offer any additional insights to help resolve this issue?

Thank you for your continued support!

Comment: @prajithak When you run my linked sandbox, is the behavior there working as you expect? I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Once the "become a seller" link is clicked and the localStorage set, the UI displays the seller links until I manually clear localStorage. Can you clarify what your ***exact*** reproduction steps are?

Comment: In the provided sandbox, the "Become a Seller" link correctly displays seller links, persisting in localStorage. However, when navigating back to the index ("Auth System") page, it continues to show seller links.
Steps:
1. Click "Become a Seller."
2. Observe seller links.
3. Click "Auth System" to return.
Expected behavior: The index or home page links (Auth System, Search Bar, Home, More, Cart, Login, Become a Seller) should be displayed.
Actual: Seller links persist.
I've reviewed the initializer and useEffect, but the issue persists. Any insights for resolution would be appreciated.

Comment: @prajithak I see, based on your description in that last comment it sounds like it's all working and persisting like you requested originally. Did you read the last sentence of my answer that stated how you toggle the "show seller links" back to false is an exercise I left for you? If you want the state to reset when the `"Auth System"` link is clicked, then add another `onClick` handler to that link to toggle the `showSellerLinks` state false. I've added this in the linked sandbox.